# Wordpress isn't pulling font-awesome fonts

Tags: css, wordpress, fonts

I'm using the maxcdn font-awesome url: https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css

The CSS pulls in fine and points to the fonts as expected (I can go to the file's the css references and they are there). However, in Chrome, the fonts aren't listed as resource and all font-awesome characters are a square. I've tried adding the fonts locally but I get the same result.

I also tested it against TwentySixteen and it didn't work there either.

I get the same result if I host the fonts and css myself. I've tested the font location in the css file and it points to the fonts correctly.

Comment: Maybe you have cross domain issue: https://davidwalsh.name/cdn-fonts

Comment: added that and tested per the link using the `curl` command. Same issue.

Comment: Not getting any errors on the page either. It's not even loading local fonts...

Comment: Other fonts loaded via CDN work as expected. Seems to just be font-awesome

Comment: clear cache, and try again

Comment: Give us a link to your site.

Answer (score 0):

Scenario 1 : Check Permission (press f12 and see console for error).

Scenario 2 : Add fonts using wp_enqueue_style in function.php (footer = true).

After that clear cache or you can check on incognito.